# How to show data in Datatables in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, promise, datatables

Data is appending next to the datatable, not inside.

I am fetching data (array of records) from an API in actions of vuex and returning state (array) from getters to the components where datatables have been used.

```
import axios from "../../assets/constants";
import router from '../../router'

const state = {
    users: []
}
const getters = {
    users: state => state.users,
    blockedUsers: state => state.blockedUsers,
    user: state => state.user
}

const actions = {
    async getUsers({ commit }) {
        await axios.get(`user`)
            .then(res => {
                commit('setGetUsers', res.data)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.message));
    })
},

const mutations = {
    setGetUsers: (state, newUsers) => (state.users = newUsers),
}

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
}
```

```
<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["getUsers"])
  },
  computed: mapGetters(["users"]),
  created() {
    this.getUsers();
    $(".zero-configuration").DataTable();
  }
};
</script>
```

Result should be as that data that I am fetching from API must show inside datatable.

As far I understand, issue that has been causing here is that

### $(".zero-configuration").DataTable();

this is executing before

### this.getUsers()

which shouldn't be correct explanation because I have used await with axios.

Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like your mixing/matching jquery with vue. Could be an issue with order as a result of that

Comment: @ekjcfn3902039 it could but I have found the solution. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out when I commit mutation after I get response from axios, it takes time to set the state. Since I am not using promise here, while the state is being mutate,

> $(".zero-configuration").DataTable();

takes control from

> this.getUsers()

and get executed before it finishes.

I encountered this problem by using promise in getUsers action

```
getUsers({ commit }) {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            await axios.get(`user`)
                .then(async res => {
                    await commit('setGetUsers', res.data)
                    resolve()
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data.message));
        })
    },
```

Now it works like a charm!